# how do i upload virtual pc into a wesite using virtual server

Tags: microsoft-virtual-server

my school has given me a project on virtual pc and server. i am supposed to create a website with multiple virtual pcs in it.. students are supposed to go to the website and than to the virtual pc and do their lab experiments there... can i no how m i to do that and how do i upload a virtual pc into the website.. i m using ms virtual server 2005 r2..

Ragu

Answer (score 1):

That's a hell of a school project. I think what you are asking is can you run the virtual pc on the web server and let the students access the VM on the website.

If this is to be done in the school I think your best bet is to run the VM on a machine and then let the students remote desktop to the VM.

Then again, I may have completely misunderstood you, unfortunately you haven't given us much info.